# Migrate Spring Web Application (web.xml) to Spring-boot 1.5.10

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-boot, web.xml

I have three applications in production and I am trying to migrate one application at a time to Spring-boot 1.5.10. We use Basic Authentication and the users credentials are either in **tomcat-users.xml** file, if the application is deployed in Tomcat, or in **application-users.properties** file, if is Wildfly. Our configuration allows the user to authenticate once, without having to authenticate in each application.

I'm having trouble migrating a small part of my **web.xml** to Java, see below:

```
<web-app>
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
        <description>Protects all resources</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
   </login-config>

   <security-role>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
   </security-role>

   <error-page>
     <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
     <location>/aviso_page.jsp</location>
   </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Here is my attempt to configure in java. My **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** is:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired MyAuthProvider myAuthProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
             .authorizeRequests()
             .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
           .and()
             .httpBasic()
             .realmName("myRealm")
          .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
         auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthProvider);
    }
 }
```

My **AuthenticationProvider** is:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    Object login = authenticationToken.getPrincipal();
    Object password = authenticationToken.getCredentials();

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }

}
```

With this Java configuration, I can't authenticate using tomcat-users.xml or application-users.properties, nor can I share authentication between the three applications.

So, what am I doing wrong?